# What does for (;;) mean in Perl?

Tags: perl, loops

I was looking though a fellow developers code when I saw this ..

```
for (;;){
   ....
   ....
   ....
}
```

I have never seen ";;" used in a loop. What does this do exactly?

Comment: fyi, this structure isn't unique to perl; I'd bet most languages with a for(initialize;test;update){} structure support having any of those fields empty.

Comment: A more useful question for searching would be "What does for (;;) do"

Comment: Elementary programming question!!! How come it got so many votes & views?!

Comment: Elementary perhaps, but unorthodox because it isn't clear what it does at a glance. The pattern is such that there should be things between the semi-colons, but since there are none, the double semi-colon looks like something special. As others have said, while(true) is much clearer than (;;).

Comment: @Viet: you answered your own question. It's elementary, so many people can understand it and probably tripped over it in the past; and many people can answer it.

Comment: Alex has it right.  The system does not reward posting and answering complicated and involved questions.  People do not vote on things they do not understand, so there is an extreme bias towards elementary things.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It loops forever. ';;' equates to no start value, no stop condition and no increment condition.

It is equivalent to

```
while (true)
{
   ...
}
```

There would usually be a conditional `break;` statement somewhere in the body of the loop unless it is something like a system idle loop or message pump.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Mitch! Now that I view it as "loops forever because of no specified parameters" it makes perfect sense.

Comment: The note on infinite loops in "Learning Perl" notes that although the for form is the idiomatic one in Perl is the while form (they recommend while(1) ).

Comment: @Ben: if you liked that, check out the `-->` operator, as in `while ($x --> 0) { ... }`.

Comment: @Ether - It's not nice to play tricks on future programmers with the parser.  ;)  I had to play with the RHS of the condition for a sec to make sure I understood what that was doing, as I don't think I'd seen that before in perl5. +1 for making me think.

Answer (score 10):

All 3 parts are optional. An empty loop initialization and update is a noop. An empty terminating condition is an implicit `true`. It's essentially the same as

```
while (true) {
   //...
}
```

Note that you it doesn't have to be all-or-nothing; you can have some part and not others.

```
for (init; cond; ) {
  //...
}

for (; cond; update) {
  //...
}

for (init; ; update) {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Infinite loop. A lot of the time it will be used in a thread to do some work.

```
    boolean exit = false;

    for(;;) {
        if(exit) {
            break;
        }
        // do some work
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Just like in C, the `for` loop has three sections:

- a pre-loop section, which executes before the loop starts.
- a continuing condition section which, while true, will keep the loop going.
- a post-iteration section which is executed after each iteration of the loop body.

For example:

```
for (i = 1, acc = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    acc += i;
```

will add up the numbers from 1 to 10 inclusive (in C and, assuming you use Perl syntax like `$i` and braces, in Perl as well).

However, nothing requires that the sections actually *contain* anything and, if the condition is missing, it's assumed to be true.

So the `for(;;)` loop basically just means: don't do any loop setup, loop forever (breaks notwithstanding) and don't do any iteration-specific processing. In other words, it's an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

Infinite Loop (until you break out of it).

It's often used in place of:

```
while(true) { // Do something }
```

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea to use in instead of `while(true) { ... }`. It only confuses noobs.

Comment: For those of us who come from C++ using VS, while(true) throws up a warning when compiling but for(;;) does not.  Projects that run 0 compiler warnings are forced to use for(;;) and it carries over when you switch languages.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same as

```
while(true) {
   ...
}
```

It loops forever.

You don't need to specify all of the parts of a for loop. For example the following loop (which contains no body, or update token) will perform a linear search of `myArray`

```
for($index = -1; $myArray[++$index] != $target;);
```