# What does the for(;;) (2 semi colons) loop mean?

Tags: perl, freeswitch

I'm working on a script for the VoIP software, Freeswitch.  The script will run as an instance listening for inbound messages to a socket.

I used an example script provided with Freeswitch, to start with, and everything works fine.

However, one bit is throwing me off.

```
use IO::Socket::INET;
use warnings;
use strict;


my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET ( LocalHost => '127.0.0.1',  LocalPort => '8060',  Proto => 'tcp',  Listen => 1,  Reuse => 1 );
die "Could not create socket: $!\n" unless $sock;


for(;;) {
    my $new_sock = $sock->accept();
    my $pid = fork();
    if ($pid) {
      close($new_sock);
      next;
    } 
    close($new_sock); 
}
```

What exactly does the `;;` mean? Is it a special operator that is defined when a socket is created? Struggling to find documentation!

Comment: It just means to loop forever.

Comment: `for (;;) { ... }`, `while () { ... }` and , `while (1) { ... }` compile identically into an "inifinite" loop. On the other hand, `{ ... }` compiles into loop that only executes once. You can use `next`, `last` and `redo` with these loops (even `{ ... }`), just like all other loops.

Comment: Syntax::Feature::Loop adds `loop { ... }`, which does the same thing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737550/what-does-for-mean-in-perl

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`for(;;)` is a C-ish idiom which is read as `for ever`, and is a loop that never terminates. People who don't come from C would write `while (1)` instead.

Normally, this C-style `for` loop has three statements: initialization, looping condition, and some step:

```
for (init; condition; step) {
    body;
}
```

which is exactly equivalent to

```
{
    init;
    while (condition) {
        body;
    }
    continue {
        step;
    }
}
```

An empty `condition` is taken to be always true.

A common usage would be to iterate over all numbers in a range:

```
for (my $i = 0; $i < @array; $i++) {
    say $array[$i];
}
```

However, this would be written more idiomatically with a foreach loop:

```
for my $i (0 .. $#array) {
    say $array[$i];
}
```

or

```
for my $item (@array) {
    say $item;
}
```

which is why you see the C-style for loop very rarely in idiomatic Perl code.

This construct is documented in [`perldoc perlsyn`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#For-Loops).

Comment: "written more idiomatically" assuming `scalar(@array)` doesn't change

Answer (score 1):

It's just an infinite loop, equivalent to writing `while(1)`.

It works because Perl has a C-style `for` loop with three parameters: an initialization, a condition, and an expression to execute on each loop.

Normally, this would be something like `for(x=0; x<10; x++)` meaning "initialize `x` to 0, test if `x` is less than 10, and increment `x` each time around the loop".

The trick is that **all three are optional**, so `for(;;)` means "initialize nothing, test nothing, and do nothing special at the end of the loop".

Comment: There is no `true` language word in Perl

Comment: @Borodin Fair point; I got a bit confused about which language was being discussed for a while. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

its just an infinite loop, as in case of C programming language.
Your code will get stuck at this statement for eternity ..
or in your case, execute the for block till the program is manually terminated.